# How to flip sprite and all collision children of a KinematicBody2D at the same time?

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

I have tried to use the `scale` property of `KinematicBody2D` to flip at the same time the sprite and the collision/area/raycast children. For flipping, one just has to set `scale.x = -1`.

If it works in the editor, it does not work properly because the engine seems to reset `scale.x` to 1 each frame (as stated [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17405)):

---

[image]

NB: Here the original sprite is looking left (that is why it is blinking when going to the right, not very didactic sorry).

---

How to do the same without flipping every collision children one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great workaround I have found [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17405#issuecomment-695974330):

```
func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    if is_on_wall():
        _direction *= -1
    var scale_x_transorm = 1
    if _direction.x > 0: scale_x_transorm = -1
        set_transform(Transform2D(  Vector2(scale_x_transform, 0         ),
                                    Vector2(0,                 1         ),
                                    Vector2(position.x,        position.y)))
```

More details [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/matrices_and_transforms.html), on how transformations work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if we only need to flip the `Sprite`, we can use `flip_h` on the `Sprite`. However, given that we also want to flip `RayCast2D`, `Area2D` and other stuff, that solution won't work.

As you noticed, we cannot flip the scale of the `KinematicBody2D` because Godot resets it when it moves. However, we can flip the scale of a `Node2D` that has the `KinematicBody2D` as child, or that is child of a `KinematicBody2D`.

In this case, I suggest to have use an auxiliary `Node2D` as child of the `KinematicBody2D`, just to be flipped, let us call it `Inner`. So your scene tree would go like this:

```
KinematicBoyd2D
├─CollisionShape2D
└─Inner
  ├─Sprite
  ├─RayCast2D
  ├─Area2D
  │ └─CollisionShape2D
  └─OtherStuff
```

And then you can flip that `Inner`, for example with the sign of the horizontal velocity of the `KinematicBody2D`:

```
var dir := Vector2(100, 0)

func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    var vel = move_and_slide(dir, Vector2.UP)
    $Inner.scale.x = sign(vel.x) if vel.x != 0.0 else 1.0

    if is_on_wall():
        dir = -dir
```

*Notice ternary operation to prevent `scale.x` to be `0.0`.*

And yes, that would mean that the `CollisionShape2D` (or `CollisionPolygon2D`) of the `KinematicBody2D` won't be flipped along. It has to be a direct child of the `KinematicBody2D`. Hopefully it is symmetric and that is not a problem.

Worst case, you have two things to flip: `Inner` and the `CollisionShape2D` (or `CollisionPolygon2D`).

```
var dir := Vector2(100, 0)

func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    var vel = move_and_slide(dir, Vector2.UP)
    var x_scale = sign(vel.x) if vel.x != 0.0 else 1.0
    $Inner.scale.x = x_scale
    $CollisionShape2D.scale.x = x_scale

    if is_on_wall():
        dir = -dir
```

Be careful flipping a non-symmetric `CollisionShape2D` (or `CollisionPolygon2D`), which may result in some undesired collisions. *This has worked for me with some `CollisionPolygon2D`, but not all (I also had some get temporarily stuck when flipped, seems to happen when the collision is on a single point, your mileage may vary).*

*If you need to have child `KinematicBody2D`, they can be inside `Inner` too.*

Comment: How do you produce a unicode tree?

Comment: @pietrodito I just copied the characters. You can find them here: [Box-drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

Comment: My main problem is that my collision shape is asymetrical regarding to the sprite, even if it is a rectangle.

Comment: @pietrodito Expanded. Moving collision shapes in general is problematic, but I don't have a better solution right now.

Comment: What do you think of this applied to the KinematicBody2D: `set_transform(Transform2D(Vector2(-1, 0), Vector2(0,  1), Vector2(position.x, position.y)))`

Comment: @pietrodito Tested. That works better than I expected. Edit: managed to get `CollisionPolygon2D` temporary stuck while using that. So I guess there is no way around being careful with what collision shape we choose.

Comment: I am really happy with it. I am gonna make an answer based on that. Do you think it is helpfull  to store last transformation to not do Transform Computing each frame?

Comment: @pietrodito It would be changing the transform since the `KinematicBody2D` is moving anyway. When you set the transform, it stores it and marks it dirty. Thus, I'd say, no, there is no need to store the transform. Go ahead and post your answer.

Comment: Got another idea... Using a root `Node2D` with the `KinematicBody2D` as a child. Then do all scales operation on the Node2D. Does it sound good?

Comment: @pietrodito Did you run into trouble with your solution? I would do use the `KinematicBody2D` as child of the `Node2D` if I didn't need `move_and_slide` et.al. Which presumably you do. Because otherwise the `KinematicBody2D` would move off center of the `Node2D` and then flipping the scale of the `Node2D` teleport the `KinematicBody2D`, so you need to move the `Node2D`, which means you cannot use `move_and_slide` et.al.

Comment: Thanks, no my solution is just fine for now. I want to inverse gravity and be able to jump on enemies in this situation, so I need all CollisionShape upside down.